# Why I'm unable to find npm installed version?

Tags: node.js, angular

Recently I have installed node js, initially it was showing output of node --version and npm --version after running in powershell.
But in powershell i got a line to update npm --version. so I run the command, meanwhile my internet got disconnected & it threw an error.
Since then, the powershell is not showing npm --version output even I haven reinstalled the complete setup of node js. I'm newbie in the domain.

[image]

I have reinstalled the complete setup, searched on Google but not getting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, you try this command to check:- `npm -l`

And then you find npm version command Like this :- `npm version`,

And here you can find the **Npm version**

Comment: Have followed ur suggestion, still It's giving the same error as i have attached in question image link

Comment: try to install using first option of this link:-https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04